# Unable to display certain images on LaunchScreen

Tags: ios, xcode, image

I have an image I created in Sketch3 just like every other image and for some reason this specific one just won't show in the UIImageView I dragged into my launchScreen.

I tried various things and It just won't show on my device. It does show on the simulator. I added the image just like all the others in my Xcode project.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: there is not enough info here,  but my guess is,  you have a case sensitive problem with your file names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. Try to remove the app from your phone, and reinstall it after a reboot. That fixed it for me...