# iOS Launch Screen Logo as UIImage with autolayout issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, autolayout, launch-screen

I am having a problem using the new Launch Screen storyboard

I am trying to make a launch screen with my application logo so

I added a `UIImage` assigned it my app logo and added the the Auto layout constraints , run the app but all I am getting is an empty image with the tint color I choose

[image]

if I try to remove the Auto layout constraints , it works just fine but of course  in a wrong position

*** Autolayout constraints ***

[image]

Comment: how did you set the Auto layout constraints ?

Comment: What constraints did you set there?

Comment: center horizontally and vertically in container

Comment: can you print that and add to the post?

Comment: See Updated Question @UlyssesR

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423223/unable-to-display-certain-images-on-launchscreen Can you try if it solves your problem too?

Comment: @panda, check the answer, see if it helps.

Comment: can you upload demo here ?

Comment: I 'll try to make a demo

Answer (score 2):

You must set also the image Aspect Ratio or Size.

Check this sample, do the same, it will work as expected.

[image: Sample]

**Source**: http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

Comment: i tried doing height , width , aspect ratio still not working

Comment: did you remove all other constraints and set as the sample image?

Comment: yes :) , but Roel Koops comment seems to work , i even did command-K but didn't work i had to completely remove the app

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you need to constrain the height and width, as well.

Comment: tried height , width , aspect ratio still not working